# Puntero vs. Referencia

Tags: c++

**Autor original de la pregunta**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference

> Jack Reza https://stackoverflow.com/users/20349/jack-reza

¿Qué sería mejor práctica a la hora de pasar la variable original a la función para trabajar con ella por:

```
unsigned long x = 4;

void func1(unsigned long& val) {
     val = 5;            
}
func1(x);
```

o por:

```
unsigned long x = 4;

void func2(unsigned long* val) {
     *val = 5;
}
func2(&x);
```

¿Hay alguna razón para elegir uno sobre el otro?

Comment: ¿Has utilizado un sistema automático para esta traducción? No soy capaz de entender la pregunta si no es por contexto...

Comment: @Darkhogg espero se entienda mejor si tienes una traduccion mejor puede proponerla, pero ten en cuenta la pregunta original Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel el concepto de puntero es de C, y por otra parte me parece que la respuesta original no tiene nada que ver con la aritmetica de punteros, el manejo o no de punteros

Comment: @Santi92 no se que esta tratando de decir con -> "el concepto de puntero es de C..." los punteros heredados de C en el lenguaje C++, como C los heredo de B, y B de BCPL (aunque BCPL usaba 'rv' y no '*'. Los punteros son una de las estructuras básicas de todas las arquitecturas "o casi". existen M. de procesadores que no se basan en punteros aunque internamente si los usan, ver ZPU. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel me referia a que por más que en C++ existan, no es correcto usarlo ya que es un lenguaje OO, por eso mencione que el concepto es de C. Saludos

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114180/pointer-vs-reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Punteros y referencias son conceptualmente lo mismo, si bien existen sutiles diferencias entre ellos. La más remarcable de ellas (y probablemente, la menos importante, aunque sí más cómoda y legible), es que las referencias no precisan de la sintaxis flecha `->` que necesitan los punteros para acceder a miembros (en el caso de que un objeto (`class`) o registro (`struct`) sea apuntado), o el operador de acceso `*`, sino que utilizan su mismo nombre para acceder al valor, y el operador `.`, el que se usaría con el mismo objeto, para acceder a los miembros.

Las referencias fueron inventadas, de hecho, para no tener que utilizar punteros cuando se realiza un paso por referencia (y para las devoluciones por referencia), es decir, cuando se desea que los cambios realizados dentro de la función llamada al objeto apuntado repercutan en la función llamadora.

Este código es relativamente complejo para lo que en realidad se desea obtener:

```
unsigned long x = 4;

void func2(unsigned long* val) {
     *val = 5;
}
func2(&x);
```

Mientras que la versión con referencias es mucho más legible:

```
unsigned long x = 4;

void func1(unsigned long& val) {
     val = 5;            
}
func1(x);
```

Así, en cuanto a la pregunta específica, desde luego creo que el uso de referencias es lo más adecuado. La pregunta subyacente es: ¿pueden siempre emplearse referencias en lugar de punteros? La respuesta es no, pues las referencias conllevan varias limitaciones inherentes a su funcionamiento:

- Las referencias no pueden ser inicializadas a NULL o nullptr. Es más, ni siquiera se pueden crear sin haber sido inicializadas. Y una vez inicializadas, no se puede cambiar el objeto o valor al que apuntan.
- No se puede utilizar aritmética de punteros con una referencia. Por ejemplo, no se puede recorrer un vector de objetos con una referencia, pues no se puede cambiar el objeto al que apunta una vez creada.

Así, el siguiente código no puede ser escrito con una referencia:

```
Persona * p = personas;

for(; ( p - personas ) < MaxPersonas; ++p) {
    cout << p->getNombre() << endl;
}
```

De ahí las "reglas de oro" aparecidas en la otra respuesta: si necesitas apuntar a más de un objeto, o necesitas indicar que no se apunta a nada (valor NULL), o precisas utilizar aritmética de punteros, entonces no puedes utilizar referencias. Cuando puedas utilizarlas, sin embargo, no dudes en hacerlo, pues son mucho más legibles gracias a su sintaxis.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 3):

Una diferencia importante es que los punteros pueden ser comparados con NULL y las referencias no.

Aunque estas cosas siempre son subjetivas una de las reglas de estilo más aceptadas es la de Google (https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments) en la que recomienda pasar argumentos por referencia solo para valores que nunca cambian (const). Si los argumentos pueden cambiar recomiendan pasarlos como punteros para poder, entre otras cosas, confirmar que no son NULL. De forma más general dicen que las referencias tienen comportamiento de punteros pero sintaxis de valores lo que hace que sean confusas.

Answer (score 2):

**Autor original**

> Nils Pipenbrinck https://stackoverflow.com/users/15955/nils-pipenbrinck

Mi regla de oro es:

Utilice punteros si usted quiere hacer aritmética de punteros con ellos (por ejemplo, incrementando la dirección del puntero al paso a través de una matriz), o si alguna vez tiene que pasar un NULL-puntero.

Utilizar referencias de otra manera.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si la función que recibe la variable ha de utilizar otra función que requiere un puntero a esa variable? Por ejemplo paso una variable long que voy a querer escribir en un fichero con fwrite( puntero_a_var, sizeof(long), 1, file) , el cual necesita un puntero a la variable. ¿Debiera pasar la variable como puntero o como referencia?

Comment: creo entender su pregunta, si usted crea una funcion (mirar respuesta de @Baltasarq "muy buena por cierto"), y basandose en ella decide crear una funcion digamos principal que requiera una variable_long&, pero dentro de esa funcion se requiere una varible_long*, pues usted puede usar suFuncion(&variable_long) para llamar a la funcion(variable_long* ...)